# Find any text with comma or space

Tags: python, regex

I have some text. You can see it here.

```
str1 = '{5723647 9 aqua\t \tfem nom/voc pl}{5723647 9 aqua\t \tfem dat sg}{5723647 9 aqua\t \tfem gen sg}'
str2 = '{27224035 2 equo_,equus#1\t \tmasc abl sg}{27224035 2 equo_,equus#1\t \tmasc dat sg}'
```

Here is what I want to get:

```
result1 = [('aqua', 'fem nom/voc pl'), ('aqua', 'fem dat sg'), ('aqua', 'fem gen sg')]
result2 = [('equus#1', 'masc abl sg'), ('equus#1', 'masc dat sg')]
```

As you see here can be two variants:

1. (anytext,)(word-I-need)\t \t(form-I-need).
2. (anytext )(word-I-need)\t \t(form-I-need).

Here is regex what I've tried:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\d* \d*(?:,| )(.*?)\t \t(.*?)}')
```

Here is what I get:

```
[('aqua', 'fem nom/voc pl'), ('aqua', 'fem dat sg'), ('aqua', 'fem gen sg')]
[('equo_,equus#1', 'masc abl sg'), ('equo_,equus#1', 'masc dat sg')]
```

However, the second must be:

```
[('equus#1', 'masc abl sg'), ('equus#1', 'masc dat sg')]
```

What could you advice? Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output for this case: `23467 23 sfhd,fds fsf\t \tydfjskdfk`

Comment: @nhahtdh: there can't be such strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\{(?:.*?,|.*?)(\S+)\t \t(.*?)\}")
```

Comment: Would you be willing to add a more robust answer, like using pattern after you've compiled it?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a minority opinion, but why not use the regex logic for things which are easier to write using a regex and then Python for the rest?  Among other things, it's more robust to changes.  Something like

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> str1 = '{5723647 9 aqua\t \tfem nom/voc pl}{5723647 9 aqua\t \tfem dat sg}{5723647 9 aqua\t \tfem gen sg}'
>>> str2 = '{27224035 2 equo_,equus#1\t \tmasc abl sg}{27224035 2 equo_,equus#1\t \tmasc dat sg}'
>>> 
>>> pattern = re.compile("{([^\}]*)}")
>>> 
>>> def extract(part):
...     ps = part.split()
...     word = ps[2].split(',')[-1]
...     form = ' '.join(ps[3:])
...     return word, form
... 
>>> for s in str1, str2:
...     for entry in re.findall(pattern, s):
...         print extract(entry)
... 
('aqua', 'fem nom/voc pl')
('aqua', 'fem dat sg')
('aqua', 'fem gen sg')
('equus#1', 'masc abl sg')
('equus#1', 'masc dat sg')
```

Comment: Text is about 100 MB and contains about 970000 lines like these. It can be too long. :-)

Comment: Another option (along the same lines) is to break it down into multiple passes with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
([^{\s,]*)\t \t([^}]*)
```

Comment: I can't get this to assign to a variable, let alone compile. Would you show an example?